# StatLight hangs when run from TeamCity as single command

Tags: silverlight-4.0, teamcity, statlight

I'm running TeamCity 6.5 on a Windows Server, with a couple of build agents on the same server (all running as the system user as services).  I had been building SilverLight projects and running the StatLight (v 1.4.4147) tests previously under Jenkins with no problems.  On Jenkins, I called the StatLight test in a custom script as follows:

```
StatLight.exe -x="Tests.xap"
StatLight.exe -x="MoreTests.xap"
StatLight.exe -x="EvenMoreTests.xap"
```

... etc., but when I migrated my build jobs to TeamCity, I also changed these into a single command line step as follows:

```
StatLight.exe --teamcity -x="Tests.xap" -x="MoreTests.xap" -x="EvenMoreTests.xap"
```

This works about 50% of the time, but when it fails, there's no output in the build log to tell me why - I just get:

```
[11:41:18]: [MyProject\bin\Release\MoreTests.xap] Tests.ExtensionsTests.WatchObservableCollection
[11:41:18]: [MyProject\bin\Release\MoreTests.xap] Tests.SubscribingModelBaseTests.DisposeIsCalled
[11:41:18]: [MyProject\bin\Release\MoreTests.xap] --- Completed Test Run at: 28/09/2011 11:41:18. Total Run Time: 00:00:11.8125000
[11:41:19]: [MyProject\bin\Release\MoreTests.xap] Test run results: Total 6, Successful 6, Failed 0, 
[11:41:19]: [Step 5/6] MyProject\bin\Release\EvenMoreTests.xap (9m:42s)
```

... and then nothing more.  The time reported in that last line just goes up and up until I kill the the build job.  Adding the --debug switch to StatLight doesn't improve the above output either.

Right now, I've switched the TeamCity build step to call each test individually as I was in Jenkins, but this is more of a workaround than a proper solution.  And of course, I may still run into the above problem - I've yet to find out.

What I'd like to know is what steps I can take to debug this issue properly, or whether there are known issues that can cause the above behaviour?

Comment: I am having the same problem, did you find a solution after all?

Answer (score 0):

There was one issue fixed in the 1.5 version relating to teamcity. http://statlight.codeplex.com/workitem/13654

I'm not sure it will fix your issue, but would you mind upgrading, trying and reporting back?

Comment: I upgraded but, unfortunately it didn't solve the issue above.  Running the tests individually (as per the first code snippet in the OP) seems to work consistently.